# Straight-edge and Compass construction references?

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I'm looking for a good reference that contains step-by-step instructions of various straight-edge and compass constructions. Google isn't helping me as much as I thought it would!!

Thank you

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["Resource for learning straightedge and compass constructions"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/240232/409)

Comment: Start here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction