# Construct a segment with length of $\frac{2a}{a+b^2}$

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Given the following segments how would you construct a segment with length of $\frac{2a}{a+b^2}$?
Given the three line segments below, of lengths a, b and 1, respectively:[image]

For example if I wanted to construct a segment $z$ satisfying an equation $a^2=b^2-z^2$ I could create a right triangle but I'm kind of stuck on what geometric figure to try to play with given this length.

Comment: Related and possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221802/compass-and-ruler-construction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a length defined as $1,$ we can construct any length that is described by addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and taking square root of positive elements.

[image]

Comment: Would I be able to use this figure http://i.imgur.com/1prZJ2w.jpg  and let $x=a+b^2$ and $y=2$ and $z=a$ to get that $w$ is the desired length wanted by similar tirangles

Answer (score 1):

Without giving the full answer away, the following diagram should give you a hint of one way to use the steps given by [Will Jagy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/10400/will-jagy) to obtain the required segment. 
You will need to figure out the lengths of the segments indicated by the grey boxes.

[image]