# Prove that the dual (ie, "midpoint polygon") of an isosceles trapezoid is a rhombus.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, quadrilateral

> Prove that the dual of an isosceles trapezoid is a rhombus.

Here, the "dual" of any polygon is where its sides intersects the midpoint of each side of the "outer" figure. (In other words, it's the ["midpoint polygon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_polygon).)

I'm aware of the properties of an isosceles trapezoid:

- By definition, the legs are congruent.
- The lower and upper base angles are congruent.
- Any lower base angle is supplementary to any upper base angle.

Here is my drawing of the dual polygon in the isosceles trapezoid:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW7Kt.jpg]

I showed that $\triangle FAE\cong\triangle HDE$ by SAS, and that $\triangle GBF\cong\triangle GCH$ by SAS. So by CPCTC, $\overline{FE}\cong\overline{HE}$, and $\overline{FG}\cong\overline{GH}$.

> I'm unsure of how to show that all of the sides of the dual quadrilateral are congruent, making it a rhombus.

Comment: the "midpoint polygon" of any convex quadrilateral is a parallelogram, the sides of the parallelogram are parallel to the two diagonals of the quadrilateral. You should draw in diagonals AC and BD.  With more effort, in any convex quadrilateral, we can inscribe a rhombus, edges parallel to the diagonals of the quadrilateral http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173016/inscribing-a-rhombus-within-a-convex-quadrilateral

Answer (score 3):

By properties of the midpoint polygon, each side of the midpoint polygon is parallel and equal to half the length of a diagonal (why?). An isosceles trapezoid has diagonals of equal length, hence the result.

> Consider the triangle $\Delta ABC$. As $AF=FB$ and $BG=GC$, we get $\Delta BFG\sim\Delta BAC$ and the similarity ratio is a half. The other sides of the midpoint polygon follows somewhat similarly.

Compare with [Varignon's theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varignon%27s_theorem)

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Since G and E are the base midpoints of the isosceles trapezoid, BC $\perp$ GE. Since  F and H are the side midpoints of the isosceles trapezoid, BC || FH. Therefore, GE $\perp$ FH.

Since GOHC and GEDC are similar, GO:OE = CH:HD = 1:1. Also, FO = OH = $\frac14$ (BC + AD). Therefore, O bisects the perpendicular GE and FH, which leads to that the four right triangles are congruent, hence a rhombus.

Comment: Is there a theorem that indicates that BC ⊥ GE? Or is it just obvious?

Comment: @Matt Schiff - Either you could argue by symmetry of the isosceles trapezoid. Or, identify that BAEG and CGED are congruent trapezoid.

Comment: @FoiledIt24 It's kinda 3.5 years after you'd questioned it, but I recently been trying to prove myself that the line crossing midpoints of the bases of an isosceles trapezoid is perpendicular to them. Here's the simplest way I guess: Draw segments $BE$ and $CE$, you get two equal trianges: $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle DCE$, because $AB = CD$, $AE = ED$, and by the properties of an isosceles trapezoid $\angle A = \angle D$. That being proven, we get that $BE = CE$, which means that $EG$ is not only the median of the $\triangle BEC$, but also the height.