# How to inscribe a square in an arbitrary quadrilateral using compass and straight edge

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

> Is it possible to inscribe a square in an arbitrary convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ with only compass and straight edge?

I know how to construct a square inscribed in a triangle, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: We can first inscribe a rhombus, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173016/inscribing-a-rhombus-within-a-convex-quadrilateral).

Comment: If the given quadrilateral is a long rectangle, an inscribed square may consist of a square comprising one end of the rectangle and a suitable 4th side. In this case all the vertices of the square will lie on the quadrilateral, but not all sides of the rectangle touch the square. I suspect that for some such rectangles it will not be possible for the square to touch all 4 sides. Can you please clarify the requirements?

Comment: Wikipedia's ["Inscribed Square Problem" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_square_problem#Piecewise_analytic_curves) describes Emch's existence proof for the case of piecewise analytic curves: curves of midpoints of secant segments parallel to a perpendicular set of lines determine a rhombus in some way; for an appropriate pair of those perpendiculars, the rhombus is a square. With a quadrilateral, it would seem possible to turn this strategy into something "constructive" in the broad sense of the term; whether it becomes straightedge-and-compass constructible is another matter.

Comment: so its not always possible

Comment: See here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968039

Comment: Are you requiring that vertices of the square are each on a different side of the quadrilateral?

Comment: yeah but i realized that its not always possible

Comment: The challenge is really to reveal the conditions under which it is possible.

Comment: It seems that the literature discusses this. Are you interested really in the construction?

Comment: Are you still interested in this one?

Comment: yeah i am still interested in this one

Comment: I can suggest a way to investigate effectively the subject by the aid of drawing an isosceles  right angle triangle in a triangle that touches three sides of the quadrilateral triangle. With the aid of GeoGebra you may determine if there is a solution.

Comment: I think it is always possible to do the construction: if a long rectangle is given, the solution might compute a square whose vertices lie on the sides, extended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a simple construction for the interesting case where the square must touch all four sides. (The other cases are easily constructed by starting with a square with three vertices on two sides of $ABCD$, and scaling it so its fourth vertex touches the third side of $ABCD$ using a homothety about the intersection of the initial two sides.)

[image: diagram]

Construct $E$ on $\overrightarrow{DA}$ with $\angle DCE = 45^\circ$, and $F$ on $\overrightarrow{CB}$ with $\angle CDF = 45^\circ$. Draw $CG$ and $DH$ perpendicular to $CD$ with $CD \parallel EG \parallel FH$. Let $GH$ intersect $AB$ at $I$. Then $I$ is a vertex of the square.

Drop perpendicular $IJ$ to $CD$. Construct $K$ on $\overrightarrow{DA}$ with $\angle DJK = 45^\circ$, and $L$ on $\overrightarrow{CB}$ with $\angle CJL = 45^\circ$. Then $K, L$ are two more vertices of the square and the last one can be constructed.