# Is it possible to inscribe a square in ANY quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry

Previously there was a question about constructing a square in an arbitrary quadrilateral ([How to inscribe a square in an arbitrary quadrilateral using compass and straight edge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724705/how-to-inscribe-a-square-in-an-arbitrary-quadrilateral-using-compass-and-straigh)).

There was a link to an article by C. M. Hebbert: «The Inscribed and Circumscribed Squares of a Quadrilareral and their significance in Kinematic Geometry.» Annals of Mathematics 1914-1915, Second Series, Vol. 16, No1/4, pp. 38-42.

In this article, Theorem 1 states:«In every quadrilateral may be inscribed at least one square having a vertex on each of four sides...»

The article also defines what is meant by inscribed square:«By inscribed square is meant one whose vertices lie on four sides of the figure.»

I cannot see how it may be possible to inscribe a square in any quadrilateral. Take for instance a quadrilateral with two opposite sides being very long and the other two opposite sides being very short. No square with vertices on all four sides can possibly exist in this quadrilateral as far as I can see.

Is the theorem in error, or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Not an answer, but a comment. When you say "can possibly exist in this quadrilateral " are you thinking that the square has to be inside the quadrilateral? I think that the claim allows the vertices of the square to lie on any points of the lines which form the edges, not just the segments we usually call the edges.

Comment: You are most probably correct in your interpretation of the claim.

Comment: looking into it.  I found how to construct  an inscribed rhombus, where my rhombus has edges parallel to the diagonals of the (convex)   quadrilateral. Makes sens to look into rotating the (orthogonal)  diagonals of the rhombus,  see what other rhombuses arise. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173016/inscribing-a-rhombus-within-a-convex-quadrilateral

Comment: that was the approach of Emch  https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2370404.pdf

Comment: It is clearly not possible in a rectangle that has one side much larger than the other. I wonder what it says after the "..." of the quoted theorem.

Comment: The theorem says after the «...»: «. If there is more than one such square in a given equilateral, there is an infinite number.» And that is the whole theorem. I should add that the article starts by saying: «Professor Emch has shown that in any closed convex curve at least one square may be inscribed...», and further «...the results» (by Emch) «may be extended to polygons formed by analytic arcs.» The Emch article referred to, Will Jagy also mentions. I am afraid I haven't read the Emch article. I believe «ancient mathematician»'s comment above gives the correct interpretation of Th. 1.